# Manually sign Push Package with openssl for Safari Push Notifications

Tags: safari, notifications, openssl, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

The documentation says `The signature is a PKCS #7 detached signature of the manifest file` but how does one do that with openssl?

For Passbook I found these commands:

```
openssl pkcs12 -passin pass:test -in ./Certificates.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out ./certificate.pem
openssl pkcs12 -passin pass:test -in ./Certificates.p12 -nocerts -out ./key.pem
openssl smime -passin pass:test -binary -sign -signer ./certificate.pem -inkey ./key.pem -in ./pushPackage.raw/manifest.json -out ./pushPackage.raw/signature xs-outform DER
```

Also tried with the WWDR certificate:

```
openssl smime -passin pass:test -binary -sign -certfile ~/Downloads/AppleWWDRCA.cer -signer ./certificate.pem -inkey ./key.pem -in ./pushPackage.raw/manifest.json -out ./pushPackage.raw/signature xs-outform DER
```

And zip it with:

```
zip -r ../example.zip . -x '*.DS_Store'
```

But I still get "`Signature verification of push package failed`".

Answer (score 0):

I've also encounter such problem. After trying, I figured out the different openssl version will result in different size of signature for the same manifest file. 
Originally, I was using openssl 1.0.2, 1.0.3 but with no luck, but **after I downgrade my openssl version to 0.9.8zf 19 Mar 2015 then everything works fine**, and my safari can recognize the push package (my safari version is 8.0.7 (10600.7.12), MAC OS: 10.10.4（14E46）)

my openssl command is:

```
openssl smime -sign -in manifest.json -out signature -signer push.pem -certfile AppleWWDRCA.pem -binary -inkey push.key -outform der
```